# using pyspark / spark xml to remove a few nodes

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

After loading xml into a data frame with the following:

```
df = spark.read\
        .format("xml")\
        .options(**options)\
        .load("s3a://.../.../")
```

How would I remove one node (say with xpath of /root/a/aa) and then write out the result to xml again? The original xml has thousands of node, so it's not practical to list all the ones I wan to keep. Also it would be extra helpful if this could be done using spark SQL.

Sample source xml:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <aa>
      ...
    </aa>
    <ab>
      ...
    </ab>
    ...
    <az>
      ...
    </az>
  <a>
  <b>
    <ba>...</ba>
    <bb>
       <bba>...</bba>
       ...
       <bbz>...</bbz>
    </bb>
    ...
    <bz> ... </bz>
  </b>
  ...
  <z> ... </z>
</root>
```

Sample expected output

```
<root>
  <a>
    <ab>
      ...
    </ab>
    ...
    <az>
      ...
    </az>
  <a>
  <b>
    <ba>...</ba>
    <bb>
       <bba>...</bba>
       ...
       <bbz>...</bbz>
    </bb>
    ...
    <bz> ... </bz>
  </b>
  ...
  <z> ... </z>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input & output ?

Comment: how is your current schema look like (according to the sample XML above?)